# help with Outlook Exchange server and curl

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar.app, exchange, curl

I work on a mac in a building full of PCs, and the IT department here doesn't have IMAP access turned on on the exchange servers. So I miss a lot of meetings because I don't get reminders because I access my mail via Outlook Web access.

I had written a script to scrape my Outlook Web Access calendar and turn it into iCal format, so I could get my reminders via thunderbird or iCal.app. It basically downloaded the calendar page via curl, parsed the HTML and reformatted all the appointments as ical. it wasn't elegant, but it worked. Then they changed to outlook 2007, and it doesn't work any more.

I have a sketchy knowledge of curl, and almost zero knowledge of how outlook works. Can anyone point me towards a reference for getting calendar info out of an exchange server without using outlook? If I can configure curl to get the HTML I will be happy, but if there's a more elegant way, such as getting the calendar info as XML I'll be delirious.

Comment: Can you install Mac OS X 10.6 (aka Snow Leopard)? 

Snow Leopard added support for Exchange Servers. You can use the standard Apple Mail, iCal, and Address Book applications for your office communications.

I used to use Microsoft Entourage but switched fully to Mail & iCal after installing Snow Leopard. 

This would be much easier and more reliable than screen scraping Outlook Web Access.

Comment: Oh goody! I'll get on to the IT people to upgrade me.. Are you sure this is without IMAP enabled?

Comment: Yes, native Exchange connectivity. It's not IMAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a heads up on this. The Exchange support in Snow Leopard is for Exchange 2007 and above only. If you are running Exchange 2003, like we are currently, it is not supported. There is a version of Entourage that works with Exchange 2003 and WebDav.